# how to use Token refresh in tymondesigns/jwt-auth?

Tags: authentication, laravel, laravel-5, jwt, json-web-token

**case in Laravel5.**

When I get tips it says "token expire", how can I refresh and get new token?

I have been use `JWTAuth::refresh($oldToken)` but it doesn't work.

What is the best way?

Answer (score 1):

<del>When was the last time you updated/installed the package? Version [0.5.2](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/releases/tag/0.5.2) was released a few days ago that fixed the issue with tokens not refreshing properly. Try running a composer update and see if that fixes your issue.</del>

I found that this was an issue with the package. I submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/pull/102) to fix it.

The token was being validated and and error is thrown before it got a chance to refresh the token.

Comment: installed the version is **0.5.2** , don't work , can you tell me what's wrong?

Comment: I've only submitted a pull request, but it's up to the project owner to decide if he will merge it. If he does then you can do composer update.

Comment: Version 0.5.3 was just released to fix this

Answer (score 0):

May be this code can help to get new token :

```
public function refreshToken(Request $request)
{

    $odlToken = $request->input('token');

    if(!$odlToken) 
        return response()->json(null);

    $token = JWTAuth::refresh($odlToken);

    return response()->json(compact('token'));
}
```